# Good mechanism for building multiple apps with one codebase

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

ers,

I'm building several iPhone apps, based on the same code-base. Right now I have 1 app set up, using one Project file in Xcode. I'm looking for the best way to set another app up, without copying the code.

What is a good way to do this? I'm thinking about setting a `#define` that indicates which app it is to update images and icons accordingly. However, I also need to set different app icons, Bundle ID's and so on. How do I do this?

I've read some topics on SO, but most of them speak about using library code and functions in several apps. This question is about reusing the entire app.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Reinder

Comment: this is a matter of taste mainly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to create a new app from another app **you can add a new target** to your application .
go to project then press right click on Target >> duplicate target see this http://www.codeworth.com/blog/mobile/ios-target-duplication/
then you can set a new deferent Bundle Id for the new target . and you can specify for each target a new resource (deferent design).

Answer (score 1):

I like to make an embedded framework with the shared code

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use version control to manage the different branches of the same application.

In the specific I solved a similar situation by using SVN with [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html), so that I had almost the whole code under a specific folder and multiple projects (with different `.xcodeproj` folders or specific source files in different folders). Any of the project has a prop to link to the common shared external and you're done.

I guess you can do anything similar with any version control system.

Comment: dont see how SVN helps with sharing one common codebase

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Because it is able to share a common codebase through externals, as I said I personally used it for the same exact problem of the OP so it definitely helps if used well. Every edit of the shared codebase is automatically reflected on all projects while keeping project settings and application specific sources on a per-application basis.

Comment: I dont agree (especially to the first sentence) but as I said it is taste - ill fake edit your post, take back my vote and we're good

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I edited the answer so I guess you'll be happier with it.